# Docs for Xcode Installation Issue

Tags: xcode5

I've Installed Xcode 5 and Docs for Xcode.  Docs for Xcode is requesting access to Xcode's docsets library which the Dialog box says should be at;

~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets

However it is not.  The DocSets directory is actually located in;

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets

When I click the Grant Access button I get an Open Dialog to select the path to grant access to, however I cannot drill into the Xcode.app directory from this dialog so I cannot grant access to the DocSets library.

If I look in the location suggested ~/Library/Developer there is no 'Shared' directory only a directory called Xcode.  Drilling into it I find a few folders but none for Documentation.  I suspect this has to do with the version of OS X I'm running (10.9.2) using a different structure.

Any ideas on how to complete the setup of Docs for Xcode without having my docs inaccessible in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Ensure you click update on docs for Xcode and restart Xcode. If you cannot find the shared folder in ~/Library/Developer/ then by going into Xcode preferences - downloads tab and download one of the documents their it will create the path which 'docs for Xcode' needs access for.
(I followed the same instructions and granted access to ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/Docsets)